# Where to ask questions about business processes (e.g. Inventory Management)?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking for a site to ask questions on business processes like inventory management, point-of-sale, etc. Which Stack Exchange site should I ask?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? There might be more than one appropriate sites.

Comment: @Yannis I am building an inventory system and I'd like to ask questions like how products are logged in the system if they come in different sizes (per unit / per pack / per box). And other stuff related...

Comment: A sample question would be useful here. Please [edit] your question; comments are meant to be temporary.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to ask. Based on your comment, your question seems to be related with accounting. Unfortunately, there is no Stack Exchange site for accounting.

You could try [Economics (beta) Stack Exchange](https://economics.stackexchange.com/), but its [Help Center](https://economics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) clearly states

> Off-topic
>
> Accounting: Accounting is a separate discipline, and there is no
>   StackExchange site dedicated to that matter yet.

Or you could try [Quantitative Finance (beta) Stack Exchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com/).

There might be some members who are experts in accounting. I don't see any harm in asking there.

Answer (score 2):

If it has to do with the mathematical model to optimize an inventory system then [OR.SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/) may be a good outlet.